# 32bit wix installer registrys the key to the regular and wow directories but it only deletes the regular one in wix

Tags: wix

my installer is a 32 bit program and when I install it to a 64 bit windows 7, it writes to the both 64 and wow directories in the registry. However, when I delete the program, the wow directory key is still left there so the DotNetInstaller still marks it as installed although it is not. Here is the registry key part:

```
  <Component Id="ClientRegKey" Guid="{9239B7BA-71FA-4703-A597-355522505E7D}">
    <RegistryKey Id="Registry_Client" Root="HKLM" Key="Software\Client\Client11"
                Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" >
      <RegistryValue   KeyPath="yes" Name="Installed" Type="integer" Value="1" Win64="yes"/>
    </RegistryKey>
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your registry value element, why are you 
mentioning win64=true?? Is that even a valid attribute, I don't see it in the documentation.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registryvalue.html

I think that attribute is causing the installer to create registry entries in the regular node. By default the x86 installer on windows 7 will only create the registry entries in the Wow node. Please remove that attribute and I think it would be fine.

From the documentation it also looks like the action attribute is deprecated, take a look at that as well.